# Typing and tkinter: A journey into darkness

Tags: python, tkinter, types

I'm working on a script with a tkinter front end (not for the faint-at-heart!), and as someone who is pretty committed to the concept of strict type checking, I'm finding it a bit challenging.

tkinter is not typed, and as a result, about half the lines in my code have cascading type errors, so my code is filled with `# type: ignore` directives.

I get that type hints in Python are a sort of bolt-on afterthought, and that tkinter is a wrapper around code that approaches types differently (if at all), but I expect that a core Python library should be a bit more type hint friendly.

Is there a standard set of type stubs that can make tkinter a bit easier to work with?

Comment: Types are certainty not bolted on, while type hints certainly are. Type hints are meant to be supportive of developing python programs, so if some library does not support those, don't worry. Type hinting is an option, not a requirement.

Comment: Types vs. Type Hints: fair point, I will update the question.  I know type hints are not required, but they are very useful, and I use them where I can.  I am hoping someone had some positive experience using type hinting with tkinter and might able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe show some code snippet, so that we can understand where your problem regarding type hints with tkinter lies.

Comment: Typeshed (in the standard mypy installation) contains stub for tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as answer as I don't have reputation to post a comment.

I'm having similar issues as Watusimoto when I'm using VS Code and Pylance. Most direct use of Tkinter classes or methods raises errors in Pylance. It is not a real issue, as the code runs and it seems most other typing systems doesn't care, but it is annoying when you are strict with typehints in all other classes, methods and functions.

For example, consider trying to get values from a listbox:

```
all_items: tuple[str] = self.label1.get(0, tk.END)
```

This would raise a Pylance error:

```
Type of "get" is partially unknown
  Type of "get" is "(first: str | int, last: str | int | None = None) -> Unknown"
```

You also get a Pylance warning for the all_items:

```
(variable) all_items: Unknown | tuple[str]
```

I also looked in the [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), as proposed by @hussic but couldn't find any stub for tkinter. Maybe I looked in the wrong place?

This seems to stem from how Pylance implemented type checking though. They are having their own stubs, which for some reason doesn't work. If I right-click and choose "Go to type definition" I come to a file stored in:

```
~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.vscode-pylance-2023.3.40/dist/typeshed-fallback/stdlib/tkinter/__init__.pyi
```

The issue with the get-method seems to stem from that the annotation for the get-method is:

```
def get(self, first: str | int, last: str | int | None = None): ...
```

Just out of curiosity I added -> Any as return type here and Pylance stopped complaining. Not sure how to tackle this problem though, as changing the files manually in the typeshed-fallback package most definitely is not the way to go.